# Is there a difference in using host name vs ip address in a JDBC connection string

Tags: oracle, performance, jdbc

When using a JDBC connection string from Java to Oracle (12), is there a difference if I am using host name or IP address from performance perspective?
Will JDBC translate the IP address every time I create a connection or will it take longer if I am using hostname?

What is the preferred use? Host or IP?

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@myhost.xerox.com:1521:orcl
```

Or

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@150.130.110.55:1521:orcl
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JDBC nor its driver will resolve the hostname to an IP address, this will be delegated to lower-level Java and OS services, which will usually cache resolved IP addresses for some time.

Technically, using an IP address could have a (very minor) performance benefit, but this is better addressed using a connection pool to reuse connections.

The big downside of using an IP address instead of a hostname is that it ties your configuration to your current network setup. If your database server needs to be moved or for other reasons get a new IP address, you will need to do extra work, while using a hostname will solve this for you (apart maybe from some DNS caching effects).

In short, use a hostname.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know.

However, what you asked reminds me of the `TNSNAMES.ORA` file which contains "aliases" to databases you access. My file currently contains 57 databases. Entries look like this:

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = my_db_server)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =             -------------------
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)         ^
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)          |
    )                              Here's the host
  )
```

Some of those aliases have host as a host name, while others have their IP addresses. From my point of view, based just on my own experience, **it doesn't matter**.

Answer (score 1):

A CNAME is better than a host name or an IP address for your database connection strings. A little extra network configuration now can save you a ton of time later if you ever need to move a database to another host.

From a performance perspective, the difference between CNAME, host name, and IP address is irrelevant. If you connect frequently enough to notice the difference between a host name and an IP address then you're killing the database performance with too many connections anyway.